# dotnetrdf xml exception using QueryWithResultSet

Tags: c#, xml, sparql, dbpedia, dotnetrdf

I have an asp.net project in which, I would like to query DBPedia.
Using the following code I am getting an error:

```
public string testEndpoint()
    {

        //TEST02
        SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");
        string res = "";
        //Make a SELECT query against the Endpoint
        SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet("SELECT ?year WHERE {dbpedia:Rihanna dbpedia-owl:birthYear ?year}");

        foreach (SparqlResult result in results)
        {
            res = result.ToString();    
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());}
```

> Error message: "An exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in dotNetRDF.dll but was not handled in user code".

Even if I handle the exception the method cannot be executed. Regarding the details it says that there is an invalid XML-version 1.1.

As the XML comes from DBPedia I don't know how to change the xml version or how else I can handle this problem.

Comment: Are you declaring the dbpedia: and dbpedia-owl: prefixes somewhere?  Even though you're sending to a remote endpoint, you'd still need to make the query be `PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> SELECT ...`.

Comment: Thanks. I had not done this. But even if I add the prefixes I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Virtuoso, which is the triple store used behind the dbpedia SPARQL endpoint, has updated its XML result generation. They replaced the XML version 1.0 with 1.1 in [this](https://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/commit/b7bf79008d750a0cc0fe3f0cfc479380d0beeae1) commit. This causes the exception in the dotNetRDF parser.

[Later](http://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/virtuoso-opensource/ci/f1cf34ad3dec2bf1db53a29c311d1b2a2662b994) on Virtuoso reverted the changes in the XML header. Hopefully DBPedia will update their binaries soon, so the old XML header appears again in the SPARQL results.

Source: http://github.com/openlink/virtuoso-opensource/issues/405