# Verion number XML 1.1 is invalid

Tags: c#, xml, sparql, dbpedia

this line in my code causes this exception

```
          Uri endpoint = new Uri("http://dbpedia.org");
        string query = "SELECT ?cat   WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/London> dcterms:subject ?cat .}";

        SparqlRemoteEndpoint source = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://dbpedia.org/sparql"), "http://dbpedia.org");
        SparqlResultSet resultSet = new SparqlResultSet();
        resultSet = source.=QueryWithResultSet(query);
```

help me please
thanx

Comment: .NET doesn't support XML 1.1 as it's was never widely supported and the recommendation hasn't been updated since 2006. DBPedia doesn't require XML 1.1 though - in fact [your link](http://dbpedia.org/resource/London) returns XML 1.0.

Comment: DBPedia has started (this month: May 2015) returning XML 1.1 in response to SPARQL queries for application/sparql-results+xml. If you can ask for the JSON version, that may work better for you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214393/dotnetrdf-xml-exception-using-querywithresultset/

Comment: how get result with json format in sparql c#